# Getting value to media player from list of audio files in previous Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity with list of music files in SDcard.

While clicking on one file, a new activity is started and the selected song will be played using media controller.

While clicking next/previous button I want to play next/previous song.

How do I pass the next and previous parameters?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is, passing the arraylist in the intent and current track to be played also in the intent.

```
ArrayList<String> trackList = new ArrayList(String);
trackList.add("Track1");
...

Intent i = new Intent(<your new activity class>) ;
i.putStringArrayListExtra("Tracks",trackList) ;
i.putExtra("CurrentTrack", currentTrack) ;
getAppilcationContext().startActivity(i) ;
```